# Media Query in SCSS is not working properly

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, media-queries, scss-mixins

I tried to follow a tutorial to make a website responsive through a media query. I made a media query file in SCSS and wrote those breakpoints.

[image]

Then, imported the file in the main SCSS file [image]

But it's not working. However, the tutorial video was fine. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I can not figure out, why you use a condition & min-width together?

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaLvUVyNwL8

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the style.scss the proper inks to the files you are importing. The imports are in a different directory than the style file

layouts/mediaqueries

Further, is mediaquiries included in your "all.scss" file?

Comment: Though, I am not sure why I need to add it to the "all file" when I have imported it to the style.scss file already. However, I added it to the all.scss file and fixed the links (layouts/mediaQueries). Still doesn't work.

Comment: I was assuming that all.scss imported all the files in the layout folder. That way you would not need to import mediaqueries separately